# Does REGEX query run faster in MyISAM table than in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql

```
Select * from Table where text REGEXP '[[:<:]]car[[:>:]]'
```

Is there any difference in the performance if it is MyISAM table and if it is InnoDB one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both cause full table scan.

So there is practically no reason to "compare" performance, since the full table scan is already the thing you should avoid.

If you have an intelligence search - use builtin fulltext index or some mature 3rd party ones like Lucene or sphinx.